# Error on Logout: undefined method 'invalidate_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I'm building authentication on a Rails 5 API, and I'm having issues with the logout piece.  I'm hitting the `/logout` route and receive a 500 error reading `NoMethodError: undefined method 'invalidate_token' for nil:NilClass>`, and it then references my sessions_controller.  My sessions_controller references an `invalidate_token` method in the logout method that's declared in the Users model, and I'm stumped as to why the error is undefined in the controller when I have defined it in the model.

sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApiController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:create], raise: false

  def create
    if (user = User.validate_login(params[:username], params[:password]))
      allow_token_to_be_used_only_once_for(user)
      send_token_for_valid_login_of(user)
    else
      render_unauthorized('Error creating the session with provided credentials')
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    head :ok
  end

  private

  def send_token_for_valid_login_of(user)
    render json: { token: user.auth_token }
  end

  def allow_token_to_be_used_only_once_for(user)
    user.regenerate_auth_token
  end

  def logout
    @current_user.invalidate_token
  end
end
```

Users model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # validate unique username and email
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  has_secure_password
  has_secure_token :auth_token

  # clear token value, used to logout
  def invalidate_token
    self.update_columns(auth_token: nil)
  end

  def self.validate_login(username, password)
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    if user && user.authenticate(password)
      user
    end
  end
end
```

API Controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def require_login
    authenticate_token || render_unauthorized('Access Denied: Unauthorized Access')
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= authenticate_token
  end

  protected

  def render_unauthorized(message)
    errors = { errors: [detail: message] }
    render json: errors, status: :unauthorized
  end

  private

  def authenticate_token
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token|
      User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end
end
```

Ideally, this should get past the logout method so it can render a 200 and actually invalidate the logged in users token.

Comment: it means `@current_user` is missing, actually `nil`, right here `@current_user.invalidate_token`. Make sure `@current_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `find_by` when fetching the user record in `authenticate_token`.  If no record is found, `nil` is returned.

Either you got bad data, or your header is not valid.

Comment: To expand on this, your `authenticate_token` could be dangerous since you are not ever checking that a valid user/token is used.
I personally would change `find_by` to `find_by!` and then rescue from the not found exception and return a 401 or 403 to the requesting client.

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining that `@current_user` is `nil` so before using the `invalidate_token` on `@current_user` make sure `@current_user` is not `nil`.

I guess you are using `current_user` `method` in the `application_controller` that returns the `@current_user` so replace

```
 def logout
   @current_user.invalidate_token
 end
```

with

```
 def logout
   current_user.invalidate_token
 end
```

Comment: I do have a `current_user` method in the API Controller, but making the change you suggested didn't have an impact on the error I'm afraid.  I've posted the API Controller for your reference in case it helps shed more light on the issue, and thanks for the response!

Comment: Also I'm not sending any headers with the logout request, no header should be necessary for this request right?

Comment: You should send header

Answer (score 0):

It is because your current_user is nil.You have to send auth_token while making request for logout. With this auth_token you have to get the user, so that you can update that user for -- nil auth_token. If user not found then you have to handle the exception for this case, because your are requesting with invalid auth_token or user might not be present in your database.
Also you need to correct this

```
def logout
  current_user.invalidate_token
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately making this change didn't have an impact on the error message.  Could it be because I'm missing headers when sending the request?  I also posted the API controller since you responded in case there's more information that may be relevant to the issue, thanks for the response!